# How to save a Mat (OpenCV) to Array

Tags: java, arrays, opencv

I wrote:

```
 Mat sobel = new Mat();
 Imgproc.Sobel(threshold,sobel, sobel.depth(), 1, 0);
 Highgui.imwrite("Sobel.jpg", sobel); 
 sobel.create( sobel.height(),sobel.width(), CvType.CV_8UC(2));    
 System.out.println(sobel.dump());

 //display matrix
```

Then I tried to get an array from sobel. But I confused how to get value from Mat and put in Array.

Answer (score 3):

image filters like canny or sobel just binarize /  highlight the image.

if all you wanted was to access the pixels:

```
byte [] pixels = new byte[ sobel.height() * sobel.width() ];
sobel.get(0,0,pixels);
```

if you wanted a list of points / contours, you'd have to use http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#findContours(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int)